# Pass data to child component used with attribute selector

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a child component with an attribute type selector. How can we pass data to such component

My child component selector looks like

```
selector: '[hello]'
```

and the parent component template is written as

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let client of clients">
    <tr hello="client"></tr>
</ng-container>
```

where clients is an object as

```
clients: any[] = [
    { firstName: 'Ajay', lastName: 'Kumat' },
    { firstName: 'Vijay', lastName: 'Kumar' }
]
```

when I try to use property binding as

```
[hello]="client"
```

or use interpolation syntax as

```
hello="{{client}}"
```

I get an error as

> Can't bind to 'hello' since it isn't a known property

Stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-attribute-selector-child-pass-data

PS: I did try to google but all I get is using component selector as element

Comment: Your input property name is client, not hello. It would need to be [client]=“client”

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I did try but it doesn't work. I an using the component selector as an attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create an `Input()` property with the same name as of the attribute selector `hello`. Without any `Input()` property, you cannot pass any data to it.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[hello]',
  template: `<td>{{hello.firstName}}</td>
  <td>{{hello.lastName}}</td>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() hello: any;
}
```

parent comp

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let client of clients">
    <tr [hello]="client"></tr>
</ng-container>
```

Forked [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-attribute-selector-child-pass-data-awcpix?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: how to pass multiple input variables

Comment: @WasifKhalil `<tr [hello]="client" [inputProp]="'second prop'"></tr>` I have update the demo link as well.